# PDF file not created when program is run

Tags: python, pdf

I am trying to put a watermark on a pdf but when I run the code it does nothing , It does not create the output file what did I missed?

```
# pdf watermarkerV2

import PyPDF2


template = PyPDF2.PdfFileReader(open('super.pdf', 'rb'))
watermark = PyPDF2.PdfFileReader(open('wtr.pdf', 'rb'))
output = PyPDF2.PdfFileWriter()

for i in range(template.getNumPages()):
    page = template.getPage(i)
    page.mergePage(watermark.getPage(0))
    output.addPage(page)

    with open('watermarked.pdf', 'wb') as file:
        output.write(file)
```

Comment: Move the with open out of the for loop.

Comment: thanks , but now i got a traceback error it says SError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument
PS F:\Python\Pdf> python -u "f:\Python\Pdf\pdf2.py"
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "f:\Python\Pdf\pdf2.py", line 5, in <module>
    template = PyPDF2.PdfFileReader(open('super.pdf', 'rb'))
  File "C:\Users\padil\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\PyPDF2\pdf.py", line 1084, in __init__
    self.read(stream)
  File "C:\Users\padil\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\PyPDF2\pdf.py", line 1689, in read
    stream.seek(-1, 2)
OSError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `with` clause was within the `for` loop.

This will work:

```
import PyPDF2


template = PyPDF2.PdfFileReader(open('super.pdf', 'rb'))
watermark = PyPDF2.PdfFileReader(open('wtr.pdf', 'rb'))
output = PyPDF2.PdfFileWriter()

for i in range(template.getNumPages()):
    page = template.getPage(i)
    page.mergePage(watermark.getPage(0))
    output.addPage(page)

with open('watermarked.pdf', 'wb') as file:
    output.write(file)
```

Comment: hey man thanks for the help but now i got a Os Error [errno 22] .

Comment: what Operating System are you running this program on? I ran this program using both Python IDLE and PyCharm on Windows 10.

A suspicion I have is that your OS requires the absolute path and may not like relative paths.

I also made sure that the input PDF files are in the same directory as my Python program.

Comment: I am using windows 10 and using vscode both my pdf files and python program are also in the same directory, how do I input the absolute path? for example my program is located in F:\Python\Pdf thanks!

Comment: this should work - template = PyPDF2.PdfFileReader(open('F:\Python\Pdf\\super.pdf','rb'))

Comment: Its still giving me the same error :/

Comment: Use with open at line 5 to open the template file first then pass the file to PdfFileReader